# Semaphores with named pipe in windows

Tags: visual-c++

I want a program for windows i.e. vc++ or c language.
I'am new in windows programming
Here is my question
Using named pipe create a multiple writer scenario and
   use semaphore to synchronize among multiple writers and single reader
   and demonstrate the use of semaphore across processes.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: That's [not a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

before writing any code, I suggest reading about named pipes (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590(v=vs.85).aspx) and semaphores (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686946(v=vs.85).aspx). The multiple writers scenario is not that hard to figure out. Use the semaphore to block the desired amount of processes and pipes to communicate between them.

Comment: i read about semaphores and named pipe and i created named pipe.i'am able to do send the message through named pipe but in case of multiple writer i'am getting problem.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? "Problem" is a very general term.

Comment: i want a program to understand the semaphores that in case of multiple writer scenario...i want it for windows